# Deploying jars to remote servers using dropbox

Tags: java, maven, deployment, dropbox

I have several servers and need to sync them to the latest maven jars periodically.
I was thinking of deploying the jar with dependencies to dropbox and then my servers would automatically update to the latest version.

Is this a good or bad idea? What are the alternatives?

At the moment I have to manually SCP the JARs around or use SVN and Maven exec to run.

thxs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would stay away from using something like drop box.  It's not really intended to sync files in this way.  For instance, what does drop box do if a file is opened when an update comes down?  What does your application do when a dependent jar changes underneath it?

I think you want to use Maven Repositories(like [Nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/)) for deploying your application changes.  It allows you to version your dependencies and can organize build promotion so you can accurately determine what's is being pushed to production.

I also found an interesting [presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/wakaleo/automated-deployment-with-maven-going-the-whole-nine-yards) which covers what you are trying to do.  An automated build/deploy process is by far the best way to go.